# Count different fields in different tables using linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have 4 tables:

```
Foreign Key----FK
Primary Key----PK

ticket(id,FK_ticketopenby,FK_closeby,FK_createby,FK_tickettype)
ticketcategoies(PK_ID,name,ticketid)
user(name,PK_id) 
usertype(PK_id,designation,FK_userid)
```

user id is Foreign Key (FK) as FK_closeby,FK_createby,FK_tickettype

A user is admin or client
Ticket is Followup or user

required linq query which result

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Usertype | TicketType | Totalopen | TotalClose | TotalCreated |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    admin |   FollowUP |       324 |       2323 |          232 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: are `FK_ticketopenby`, `FK_closeby` and `FK_createby` nullable?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little thin but here is the answer to what I think you are asking.

I assume you are using an ORM like Linq-to-SQL or EF and that you have an entity for each table.

It is not clear how the Ticket Type is represented in your model so I haven't joined to that entity.

```
context.Tickets.Join(
        context.UserTypes,
        t => t.TicketOpenBy, 
        ut => ut.UserId,
        (t, ut) => new
            {
                Usertype = ut.Designation,
                TicketType = t.TicketType,
                Open = (t.TicketOpenBy ?? 0) > 0 ? 1 : 0,
                Closed = (t.CloseBy ?? 0) > 0 ? 1 : 0,
                Created = (t.CreateBy ?? 0) > 0 ? 1 : 0
            })
    .GroupBy(
        t => new { t.Usertype, t.TicketType },
        t => new
            {
                t.Usertype,
                t.TicketType,
                TotalOpen = t.Sum(t => t.Open),
                TotalClosed = t.Sum(t => t.Closed),
                TotalCreated = t.Sum(t => t.Created),
            });
```

If this nothing like the answer you were looking for you will need to add clarity and detail to your question.